# Appium encoding issue on iOS

Tags: node.js, xpath, encoding, utf-8, appium

I'm having an encoding issue using appium 1.5 and nodejs webdriver on iOS (simulator, ios 8).
The app contains following french text "News Cinéma", and I'm using an xpath expression to find this element:

```
(//*[@name="News Cinéma"])[1]
```

Appium tells me that there is no such element.

Then, when looking at the source XML I can indeed find the element, but the accentuated character "é" has a different UTF-8 code than the one my keyboard produces.

- Keyboard: é -> C3 A9
- Appium: é -> 65 CC 81

Visually that's the same character, but behind the scenes, it's a totally different utf8 code, hence the issue.
Did anyone ever encounter such issue, or knows how I can get around it ?

Thanks

ps: I don't have this problem on Android. I recently upgraded to appium 1.5 but I'm not sure wether this issue is new to this version of appium or not.

Comment: i have automated my app in 10 different languages including french, but never had any issue. Can you try by using just name driver.findelementByName("News Cinéma"); instead of xpath.

Comment: I recently upgraded to appium 1.5 and Name selector is now deprecated.
Do you think it could be related to appium version ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fix was using the capability unicodeKeyboard = true

See [capabilities documentation here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/).